# how to compare text file datas with excel sheet values

Tags: shell-script, python, perl, text, excel

For Example :

in my `username.txt` file

```
ravi
peri
perl
phython
```

in my .xls file i have two columns named as user name and email

```
username                      email
ravi                          ravi@gmail.com
peri                          peri@gmail.com
```

I want to produce the output in list order like excel view or normal list view .Please help me to solve this issue .

Comment: what have you tried?  is your excel file in .xls format or have you exported it to CSV?

Comment: i tried to convert .xls to .csv by following this step $ ssconvert Book1.xlsx newfile.csv but doesn't work to me

Comment: wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/4c/56/4c7f595525839710ab563c8e5a48226021111c1324b1460e603256f7665c/xlsx2csv-0.7.3.tar.gz
--2017-08-08 06:13:35--  https://pypi.python.org/packages/4c/56/4c7f595525839710ab563c8e5a48226021111c1324b1460e603256f7665c/xlsx2csv-0.7.3.tar.gz
Resolving pypi.python.org... 151.101.8.223, 2a04:4e42:14::223
Connecting to pypi.python.org|151.101.8.223|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to pypi.python.org|2a04:4e42:14::223|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.